# AngularJS Directive does error when input is empty

Tags: angularjs

I'm using this directive to limit my input to 5 caracters for percentage

```
   monApp.directive('awLimitLength', function () {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      attrs.$set("ngTrim", "false");
      var limitLength = parseInt(attrs.awLimitLength, 10);// console.log(attrs);
      scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(newValue) { 
        if(ngModel.$viewValue.length>limitLength){
          ngModel.$setViewValue( ngModel.$viewValue.substring(0, limitLength ) );
          ngModel.$render();
        }
      });
    }
  };
})
```

and using it like this :

```
<input name="name" type="text"  ng-model="nameVar" aw-limit-length="5"/>
```

BUt when the input is empty, firebug notice several errors like this :

```
  Error: ngModel.$viewValue is undefined


Error: ngModel.$viewValue is null
```

How could i avoid theses errors ? Thank you. 
I'd like the directive not to be started when an input is empty.

I've tried this : But it doesn't work :

```
  monApp.directive('awLimitLength', function () {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      attrs.$set("ngTrim", "false");
      var limitLength = parseInt(attrs.awLimitLength, 5);// console.log(attrs);
      if(attrs.ngModel!=null){
          scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(newValue) { 
            if(ngModel.$viewValue.length>limitLength){
              ngModel.$setViewValue( ngModel.$viewValue.substring(0, limitLength ) );
              ngModel.$render();
            }

          });
       }
    }
  };
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Check ngModel.$viewValue exist before taking its length

```
scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(newValue) { 
   if(ngModel.$viewValue && ngModel.$viewValue.length>limitLength){
      ngModel.$setViewValue( ngModel.$viewValue.substring(0, limitLength ) );
      ngModel.$render();
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thank you but where do i write this please

Comment: if(ngModel.$viewValue && ngModel.$viewValue.length>limitLength){ replace your if condition in $watch with this line

Comment: Thank you :) If it is useful and working please mark it as correct answer

Answer (score 0):

You have used 
  **require: 'ngModel'** in directive. so you can't use this directive without value in model variable.

Remove **require: 'ngModel'** & it will work.